# Android icon next to preference

Tags: android, xml, icons, preferences

I have a preference menu and i would like to have a icon on the left side of each preference item, whether its edittext or listpreference idc i want a icon next to it.

I have searched the web/googled and read alot but none of the answers seem to work.

Now could someone please tell me how i would such a thing?

I already have a custom edittext class if that helps.

My preferenceactivity looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android:icon in your xml. See this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:icon

Comment: Looks like it is not available for pre-Honecomb devices